# I need an auto task killer for windows

Tags: windows, memory, process, automation, kill

I'm looking for some software that automatically kills the program taking the most amount of ram once the ram used goes past a set threshold 
the reason why is because if I don't kill the process in time windows will start dumping unused portions of it to disk and for some reason it slows windows to a crawl when it is doing so and then I end up forcing a restart because of it

Comment: Try "**`TASKKILL /F /IM ProcessName.exe`**".... [**Taskkill**](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html). You could give it a label, stick it in a batch script with a `GOTO :Label` and loop it.... [**GOTO**](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Comment: What you want to do is unwise, given your problem. Imagine you are browsing the web and your browser gets terminated, because browsers often use most of the RAM.

Comment: I realize that but it would have to be terminated anyway because window will lock up once it's out of ram. so either way it would be killed